# index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: VARIABLE is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a variable from an HTML file in a jquery selector that contains HTML tags to a JavaScript function.

```
var $tweeter = $('<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(' + streams.home[index].user + ')"></div>');
```

Where `userTweet()` is a function in my linked JavaScript file and `streams.home[index].user` is an array of user objects with `user`, `message`, and `created_at` keys. When I click on the div, I get the error

```
index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: VARIABLE is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

With `VARIABLE` being the user name in the `user` property of `streams.home[index]`

How can I pass this variable to run the function in my JavaScript file? Please let me know if you require any further information.

Thanks!

Comment: what you doing with the $tweeter? are you append it to html? if so, how?

Comment: because you get `<div onclick="userTweet(foobar)">` Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Eduad Jacko... 
`$tweeter.text('@' + tweet.user + ' · ' + timeAgo); 
$tweeter.appendTo($tweets);`


`$tweets` is a div that I'm appending `$tweeter` to

Comment: @epascarello... Sorry, I do not see the problem. Isn't that how you add attributes to HTML? Within quotes..  The console is returning the correct user's name, but it's saying that it's undefined?

Comment: No you are saying use the variable` foobar`, not a string. Proper onclick would have quotes around the string in the arguments.

Comment: @epascarello, did you mean like this? `var $tweeter = $('<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(streams.home[index].user)"></div>');` ? I had it like this originally, but in my research I saw another post that suggested concatenating the variable. This way does not work either and also returns the same error in the console.

Comment: no because you would be passing `streams.home[index].user` to the method and not the string and `index` is not going to be the value in the loop. You need to add quoutes around it.... so it looks like `<div onclick="userTweet('foobar')">`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello! Your explanation was a little hard to follow but now that I know what I was doing wrong I totally understand. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are victim of single quotes(') and double quotes(") here.

When you tried to do

```
var $tweeter = $('<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(' + streams.home[index].user + ')"></div>');

// For Simplicity assuming streams.home[index].user value is 'mike'
```

Your string is not what you expected.

This is string that formed:

```
<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(mike)"></div>
// Note mike is not a value but as a variable here
```

This is what you expected it to be:

```
<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet('mike')"></div>
// Note 'mike' is value here
```

So when you called `userTweet` you passed a variable `mike` which doesn't exist and this error.

The difference in both the calls is `userTweet(mike)` and `userTweet('mike')`. On first call `mike` is variable(your case) and on second one it's a value.

Would recommend you to follow [this link over string and backticks in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as this provides solution to your problem.

Also just do this

```
var $tweeter = $(`<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(' ${streams.home[index].user} ')"></div>`);

// If on older version and new JavaScript is not supported then
var $tweeter = $('<div class="tweeter" onClick="userTweet(' + "'" + streams.home[index].user + "'" + ')"></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I was forgetting the quotes around my string variable which needed to be wrapped in quotes. I did at some point have a similar answer but I must have had them in the wrong place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is your `userTweet` available on window? if so then

```
$('<div class="tweeter"/>').on('click', function() {
  window.userTweet(streams.home[index].user)
})
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure, sorry, I'm still learning.. What does it mean for my function to be available on window?

For your code snippet, is it not required to close the div? I do not see the closing tag.

Comment: what you doing is more like PHP rather then JS. Maybe this would help you https://codesandbox.io/s/yq994pox7v